# Need a fix for merge update query (Simple but still confusing)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
MERGE INTO table_1 a   
USING      
 (SELECT * from table_2) b  ON ( a.row_id = b.row_id and a.in_correct IS NULL) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.in_correct = 'Y';
```

In the above query ORA-38104:Column referenced in ON clause cannot be updated.

I have been sitting for hours to resolve this.

I have identified that the problem is the field in_correct.

This field "in_correct" cannot be put in both ON clause and also after SET.  But in order satisfy my criteria,I have no option.

Please help me out

Comment: You mention: "in order satisfy my criteria, I have no option". Please let us know your criteria.

Comment: @peter:Criteria is that I want to check in the ON clause whether in_correct is NULL

Comment: @peter:I have to update a field in Table A,basde on the condition which is from field of Table A data and Table B data.So I used Merge update.The query which I have used(seen in the question of mine) fails if I specify a column name(Which is present both in update and ON clause).Hope I am clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO table_1 a USING
    (SELECT * from table_2) b 
ON ( a.row_id = b.row_id) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET a.in_correct = NVL(in_correct, 'Y');
```

UPDATE:

A more "general" command (for non null values):

```
MERGE INTO table_1 a USING
    (SELECT * from table_2) b 
ON ( a.row_id = b.row_id) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET a.in_correct = case 
                 when in_correct = 'valuetobereplaced' then 'Y'; 
                 else in_correct; 
                 end;
```

Comment: @peter This holds good for null values.But if I have a constant say value 1 all values of 1.It must be replaced with Y,what should I do

Comment: is simple: SET a.in_correct = case when in_correct = '1' then 'Y'; else in_correct; end

Comment: @peter I used replace function.It does not work.replace(1,'Y').Its not working.Is there anything like this,,A direct replace command

Comment: have you tried the command above? ... ok, i'll edit my response

Comment: @peter In the edited resoponse above,at the end of the query,after[end],If i add.. where rownum > 5,the query does not work

Comment: @peter  I am searching an alternative for set rowcount 0 which is in sybase but not in oracle....

Comment: maybe you should post another question. Nobody will read our comments. Put working code, your not-working tries, and don't forget to explain the sybase behavior.